# Go: Get filepath from ast.File

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Assume I have:

```
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, srcPath, nil, 0)
```

How can I get back the srcPath from `f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fset.Position(f.Package).Filename` to get `srcPath` from `f`.

Comment: how can I see if there is an alias to an imported package?

Comment: also can you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72933738/golang-parse-all-files-in-the-project

Comment: is there a way to get full file path? instead of just the name?

Comment: @johnydoey Call [filepath.Abs](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Abs) to convert a relative path to an absolute path.  The file set position contains the filename passed to ParseFile.  If you don’t call os.Chdir in the program, then you can convert the result of the expression in this answer to an absolute path.  If you do call os.Chdir in your program, it’s best to convert the argument to ParseFile to an absolute path.

Comment: Hi, this is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940052/go-get-alias-of-imported-package