# Go: Get alias of imported package

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a snippet like this:

```
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, ".", nil, 0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, s := range f.Imports {
    fmt.Println(i.Path.Value) //prints import path
}
```

How can I get the alias of the import? Like if I have:

```
import (
    test "github.com/username/some-repo"
)
```

How can I get the alias `test`?

Answer (score 2):

If `s` is an [`*ast.ImportSpec`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#ImportSpec), you get the import alias with:

```
s.Name.String()
```

or

```
s.Name.Name
```

The struct is defined as:

```
type ImportSpec struct {
    Doc     *CommentGroup // associated documentation; or nil
    Name    *Ident        // local package name (including "."); or nil
    Path    *BasicLit     // import path
    Comment *CommentGroup // line comments; or nil
    EndPos  token.Pos     // end of spec (overrides Path.Pos if nonzero)
}
```

So:

```
    for _, s := range f.Imports {
        fmt.Println(s.Name.String())
    }
```

Using `Ident.String()` is better because if doesn't panic if the `Ident` itself is `nil`, e.g. in case of import statements with no alias.